# k-cycles and permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm trying to understand a [proof from Yahoo Answers](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=ArPgiZQnQIXqbb0t61DlLusazKIX;_ylv=3?qid=20120209041852AANkOYp) of the following.

> (a) Show that if $μ = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) ∈ S_n$ is a $k$-cycle and $\sigma \in S_n$ is any permutation, then $\sigma μ \sigma^{−1}$ is the $k$-cycle $\sigma \mu \sigma^{−1} = (\sigma(x_1),\sigma(x_2), \dots ,\sigma(x_k))$.
>
> (b) Using the above, find a necessary and sufficient condition for two permutations in
> $S_n$ to be conjugate to each other.

It does not look like part (a) is done very clearly. Can someone explain it?

Thanks

Comment: Questions should be self-contained if possible.

Comment: What does $\mu - 1$ in the statement of (a) indicate?

Comment: probably the inverse

Answer (score 2):

What you want to prove is: Let $\mu=(x_1,...,x_k)\in S_n$ be a cycle and let $\sigma\in S_n$ be any permutation then $\tau:=\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(x_1),...,\sigma(x_k))$.
What we actually want to show is:
I. For all $1\leq i<k$, $\tau(\sigma(x_i))=\sigma(x_{i+1})$ and $\tau(\sigma(x_k))=\sigma(x_1)$.
II. If $y\neq \sigma(x_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, then $\tau(y)=y$.
For I: compute: $\tau(\sigma(x_i))=\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(x_i))=\sigma\mu(x_i)=\sigma(x_{i+1})$. Similarly, for $\tau\sigma(x_k)$.
For II: Take any $y\neq \sigma(x_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$. Now, 
$$\tau(y)=\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}(y)\overset{(*)}{=}\sigma\sigma^{-1}(y)=y$$
$(*)$ since $y\neq \sigma(x_i)$, we have $\sigma^{-1}(y)\neq x_i$, and hence $\mu\sigma^{-1}(y)=\sigma^{-1}(y)$ ($\mu$ acts non-trivially only on $x_1,..,x_k$)